# org.hibernate.AnnotationException is not annotated or on the whitelist

Tags: corda

I have tired to add @Id for primary key declaration in schema. build and ran successfully. But its shows as Class org.hibernate.AnnotationException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization Serialization trace: cause (rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException) throwable (rx.Notification) . i added @corda serializable too. please help me out.

Comment: What action do you perform to trigger this error?

Comment: i just sent a id as json object

Comment: You sent it in the context of a flow? How did you trigger the flow? Did you run it from the CRaSH shell?

Comment: i ran n intellij itself. i try to send input as JSON object in Postman

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm going to need to see the code. I can't replicate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as follows:

- Your code is throwing an `org.hibernate.AnnotationException`
- The node is trying to send this exception back to the client over RPC, or to another node as part of a flow
- For security purposes, only whitelisted classes can be serialised and sent within flows or over RPC
- The exception class is not whitelisted, so a serialisation exception is thrown instead

Once you whitelist the exception class, it will be serialised and returned properly, allowing you to diagnose the underlying issue.

**Adding classes to the whitelist**

You can add classes to this whitelist by:

- Adding the `@CordaSerializable` annotation to the class

  ```
  @CordaSerializable
  class MyClass
  ```
- Adding it to the serialisation whitelist:

  ```
  class TemplateSerializationWhitelist : SerializationWhitelist {
      override val whitelist: List<Class<*>> = listOf(MyClass::class.java)
  }
  ```

The serialization whitelist plugin's fully-qualified class name must then be added to a file called `net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist` in the `src/main/resources/META-INF/services` folder.