# Corda Class org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization

Tags: corda

I get below error when i try to query vault for my custom state.
I have 3 nodes, in my network (node 1 connected to sql server database and other nodes connected to h2 database). Below error is thrown on node 1 when querying the vault. (rpcOps.vaultQueryBy().states)

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException is not annotated or on the
>   whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization Serialization trace:
>   exception (net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Failure)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)
>   [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
>   [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>   [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
>   [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>   [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>   [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>   [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>   [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243)
>   [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
>   [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
>   [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181] Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException is not annotated or on the
>   whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization Serialization trace:
>   exception (net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Failure)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
>   ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>   ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>   ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>   ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>   ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
>           ... 14 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.AnnotationException is not annotated or on the whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633652/org-hibernate-annotationexception-is-not-annotated-or-on-the-whitelist)

Comment: so in that case should when i add SQLGrammarException class in serialization whitelist, i now get further error for SQLServerException. sqlException (org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException) Should i add the class in which code the to query vault is being written, into my serialization whitelist?

Comment: Once you've whitelisted the exception, you'll see the "true" stack trace (unless another exception needs to be whitelisted). Once you have the "true" stack trace, we can diagnose the error (in a separate SO question).

Comment: Thanks, i;ll try that and get back if any issues

Answer (score 1):

Corda restricts the set of types that can be sent between the node and a client via RPC.

In your case, your flow is throwing a `SQLGrammarException`. The node is trying to pass this object back to the client via RPC, but since it is not one of the types that can be passed via RPC, a `KryoException` is being raised instead.

You need to add `SQLGrammarException` to the node's serialisation whitelist, using the process described here: https://docs.corda.net/serialization.html#whitelisting. Once you've done this, the `SQLGrammarException` will be returned correctly and you can inspect it.